# Impex attribute modifier to check length of a value in Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I am trying to import an impex file. Currently, there is no such condition on the attributes. So, it is working fine.

However,I want to insert only those records for which the length of the value is not less than 10 characters but I haven't found any attribute modifiers in the Hybris documentation using which I can do that.

Below is my impex file:

```
Update Product;code[unique=true];value
              ;2055     ;ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
              ;2455     ;ABCDEFGH
```

Here, the first row should get inserted but not the second one since the length of value field is less than 10 characters.

Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a ValidateInterceptor that would verify the condition you require.

Make sure *impex.legacy.mode* is set to *false* otherwise the interceptor will not be triggered.

Answer (score 0):

basically you could leverage the translator on the particular column in impex file. By defining your customized translator to validate the length of that column. For example:

```
INSERT_UPDATE Media;mediaFormat(qualifier);code[unique=true];@media[translator=de.hybris.platform.impex.jalo.media.MediaDataTranslator][forceWrite=true];realfilename;altText;
```